# How to display top sellers by date range in Magento

Tags: php, magento

Is there anyway to display best sellers by date range? In example 30 days, 60 days, etc

This is my current bestsellers.phtml and we have no idea what range this data is pulling from

```
<?php
$params = $this->getData();
if(array_key_exists('limit', $params)) {
    $limit = $this->getData('limit');
} else {
    $limit = 3;
}

$products = $this->getBestSellers($limit);
?>

<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('js/overlay_jquery.js');?>"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('msslider/slider2/stepcarousel.js') ?>"></script>  
<script type="text/javascript">
stepcarousel.setup({
    galleryid: 'mygallery', //id of carousel DIV
    beltclass: 'belt', //class of inner "belt" DIV containing all the panel DIVs
    panelclass: 'panel', //class of panel DIVs each holding content
    autostep: {enable:false, moveby:1, pause:2000},
    panelbehavior: {speed:500, wraparound:true, wrapbehavior:'slide', persist:true},
    defaultbuttons: {enable: false, moveby: 1, leftnav: ['<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('msslider/slider2/arrowl.png')?>', -15, 100], rightnav: ['<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('msslider/slider2/arrowr.png')?>', -25, 100]},
    contenttype: ['inline'] //content setting ['inline'] or ['ajax', 'path_to_external_file']
})
</script>
<div class="category-products home-page-listing">
    <div id="mygallery" class="stepcarousel">
    <div class="belt products-grid">
        <?php if(is_array($products) && count($products)): ?>
            <?php $i = 0; foreach($products as $product): ?>
                <div class="panel">
                    <div class="product-topbg">
                    <div class="product-bottombg">
                    <div class="product-midbg">
                        <h2 class="product-name" style="margin: 5px 0px 15px;">
                            <?php echo $product['category_name']; ?>
                        </h2>
                        <div class="overlay" 
                            id="overlay-<?php echo $i; ?>"
                        >
                            <a href="<?php echo $product['url']; ?>"
                                title="<?php echo $product['name']; ?>"
                            >
                                <img src="<?php echo $product['image_url']; ?>"
                                    width="160" height="160"
                                    alt="<?php echo $product['name']; ?>"
                                />
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <h2 class="product-name" style="margin: 15px 0px 5px;">
                            <a href="<?php echo $product['url']; ?>"
                                title="<?php echo $product['name']; ?>">
                                <?php echo $product['name']; ?>
                            </a>
                        </h2>
                        <div class="overlay-show" 
                            id="overlay-show-<?php echo $i;?>"
                        >
                            <div class="product-price">
                                <?php echo $product['price']; ?>
                            </div>
                            <div class="price-bottombg"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                    <script type="text/javascript">
                        var $i = jQuery.noConflict(); 
                        $i("#overlay-<?php echo $i;?>").hover(function () {
                            if ($i("#overlay-show-<?php echo $i;?>").is(":hidden")) {
                                $i("#overlay-show-<?php echo $i;?>").slideDown("fast");
                            } else {
                                $i("#overlay-show-<?php echo $i;?>").slideUp("fast");
                            }
                        });
                    </script>
                </div>
            <?php $i++; endforeach;?>
    <?php endif; ?>
    </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    decorateGeneric($$('ul.products-grid'), ['odd', 'even', 'first', 'last']);
    </script>
</div>
```

Thank you for any help with this code.

Answer (score 0):

As I can see, this is the block that belongs to some 3-d party extension (or smb might have written it). That's why you should locate the block and correct the collection of products it receives via the getBestSellers method.

If you want to see only the last 3 updated products, the easiest way is to add 'order DESC' by 'updated_at' to the collection

Thus, the first 3 products will be the last updated on the list. It will look like that:

```
$collection->setOrder('update_at', Varien_Data_Collection_Db::SORT_ORDER_DESC);
```

If you want to get populated some other field, that is different from the 'updated_at', just use its name instead of 'updated_at'.

Note, that you should implement all the changes before the collection gets downloaded.

The block can be find via 'updated_at' or by means of the layout. Additionally, you can search for updated_at inside of the template. Use the most convenient for you method.

Comment: I found bestseller.php and it looks like it has all the info. However I can't find which xml file this in. This is the block code on the backend for the cms page. 

{{block type="bestsellers/bestsellers" name="bestsellers_bestsellers" limit="10" template="catalog/product/bestsellers.phtml"}}

Comment: Basically I need to create another bestsellers block to pull data from the past 7 days